# Best customizable android chart library

Tags: android, charts, android-canvas, mpandroidchart

[image: desired chart]

I need any chart library which allow me to draw lines, put images and can draw different type of data sets, In image i will have 3 set of data and want to draw at once. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart

Comment: Hmm it seems good, but i do not think so it will allow to put images in charts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually using Telerik. But I find a new open source library:

[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=9bca612ab6-Android_Weekly_142&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-9bca612ab6-337297681)

Comment: MPAC is cumbersome to use. Requires too much tinkering

Comment: I did find this one amongst others: https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartCore

Comment: Also check this out: https://androidexample365.com/tag/charts/